# Rails - Authlogic persistence_token question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I am trying to implement reset password functionality using the tutorial at http://www.binarylogic.com/2008/11/16/tutorial-reset-passwords-with-authlogic/
and facing difficulties. The problems seem to be coming from `persistence_token` not matching with what is in the database.

When does `persistence_token` get set/updated?

My password reset code looks exactly like the tutorial and here it is:

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_no_user
  before_filter :load_user_using_perishable_token, :only => [ :edit, :update ]

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email_address(params[:email])
    if @user
      @user.deliver_password_reset_instructions!
      flash[:notice] = "Instructions to reset your password have been emailed to you"
      redirect_to login_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "No user was found with email address #{params[:email]}"
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

def update
  @user.password = params[:password]
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "Your password was successfully updated"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render :action => :edit
  end
end

private

def load_user_using_perishable_token
  @user = User.find_using_perishable_token(params[:id])
  unless @user
    flash[:error] = "We're sorry, but we could not locate your account"
    redirect_to new_password_reset_path
  end
end
```

The method `load_user_using_perishable_token` is loading the value correctly from the database, however, the call to `@user.password = params[:password]` is modifying the `peristence_token` to a different one. The subsequent call, `@user.save` fails because it cannot find a record with the modified `persistence_token`.

Any ideas how to resolve this would be a great help.

Edit for clarification:

1) There is no error, @user.save returns false. 
@user.save triggers the following SQL query:

```
SELECT `users`.id FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`persistence_token` = 
  BINARY '53a6fd82a1da50c299230afd2b7911e7774f6fd62a714909194d5d84e2094444d808a71992bb8b11bc572fd865e9956681dea61bf46e3f65d9d41c53a6b0ec90' AND `users`.id <> 7) LIMIT 1
```

The persistence_token value used in the query does not match the database value.

2) I am not sure if this is a clue, but in the debugger I notice that whenever 
@user.password = params[:password] gets set, the persistence_token value changes in the @user object.

Comment: What's the error message when it fails? I suspect it fails because you didn't set `@user.password_confirmation` and the validation failed because of that.

Comment: You were right, it turned out that it needed password_confirmation. Even though my user model does not have a field for password_confirmation, that value needed to be set to successfully update the existing password. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What htanata says. You aren't setting the password confirmation. Can you give us the error messages you are getting?

And firstly you do need to set the password_confirmation or you'll be getting validation errors.

Comment: Bye the way you are mixing up perishable_token and persistence_token. The perishable_token is used for password resets etc and the persistence_token is used for 'remember me' functionallity.

Comment: James, I edited the original post and added clarification. The problem is that persistence_token value used to query for password update is not the same as database value. How do I get them to be in sync?

Comment: password_confirmation was the missing piece. there were no errors while saving so thought it wasn't needed. Thanks